# OOPS to Oracle Mapping

Tags: oracle

I am a hardcode Oracle guy and trying to lean OOPS concepts. I have mapped my understanding of Oracle concepts with OOPS. Can you please help validate my understanding?

```
Table definition --> Class
Records/Rows -->  Objects
Default value of columns --> Constructor
Creating a Type and assigning to a column --> Inheritance
Package --> Package
Package Spec --> Interface
```

Also - are there anything else that can be mapped easily?

Comment: No. Don't try to correlate Oops this way to understand it. You will not go too far. Start using any objected oriented language like Java / C++ or Python.

Answer (score 0):

To some extend , your understanding is correct.

- Column names - List of properties / attributes
- Column data type - attribute data type
- Rows - List of objects
- Default values in attributes - You can set it in constructor or in initialization.